# SKSpriteNode Won't Move

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have created a rectangular image in the form of an SKSpriteNode in Swift with the following code:

```
var screenImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(imageChoices[randomImageChoice].0)"))
screenImage.position = CGPointMake(screen1.position.x, screen1.position.y)
screenImage.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, self.frame.size.height)
self.addChild(screenImage)
```

I proceed to move the image with the following code:

```
func swipedTrue(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if gameOver == false && tutorial == false {

        //if you swipe, it checks if you were right, then moves on or GameOver()
        if (wordChoices[randomWordChoice]).1 == true {

            //reset time
            timePerQuestion = 1.0

            //randomize word
            randomWordChoice = Int(arc4random() % 3)
            newImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(wordChoices[randomWordChoice].0)"))

            //randomize color of screens, mid-swipe
            newScreen.fillColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1.0)

            //replace timeBar
            decreaseTimeBlock.fillColor = newScreen.fillColor
            decreaseTimeBlock.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.5, self.frame.size.height * 0.985)
            timeBarRedValue = 0.0; timeBarGreenValue = 1.0
            newTimeBar.fillColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(timeBarRedValue), green: CGFloat(timeBarGreenValue), blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

            //actions caused by swipe: it's "bringNewScreen" because if you swipeFalse, the newScreen comes from bottom. If you swipeTrue, it comes from the top.
            var swipeTrueCurrentScreen = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.size.width * 2, duration: 0.5)
            var bringNewScreen = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.size.height * 0.5, duration: 0.5)
            var bringNewTimeBar = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.size.height * 0.985, duration: 0.5)

            //reset the newScreen and word to the top of the screen, to be dropped again
            newScreen.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.frame.size.height * 1)
            newImage.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.frame.size.height * 1)
            newTimeBar.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.5, self.frame.size.height * 1.58)

            //swipe word and screen
            currentImage.runAction(swipeTrueCurrentScreen)
            currentTimeBar.runAction(swipeTrueCurrentScreen)
            currentScreen.runAction(swipeTrueCurrentScreen)

            //make swiping noise
            runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Swoosh 3-SoundBible.com-1573211927.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))

            //bring in the newScreen
            newScreen.runAction(bringNewScreen)
            newImage.runAction(bringNewScreen)
            newTimeBar.runAction(bringNewTimeBar)

            //increase score
            ++score
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"

            //here, switch the currentScreen with the newScreen so that the process can be repeated
            if newScreen == screen1 {

                newScreen = screen2
                newImage = screenImage2
                newTimeBar = timeBar2
                currentScreen = screen1
                currentImage = screenImage1
                currentTimeBar = timeBar1

            } else {

                newScreen = screen1
                newImage = screenImage1
                newTimeBar = timeBar1
                currentScreen = screen2
                currentImage = screenImage2
                currentTimeBar = timeBar2

            }

        } else {

            GameOver()

        }

    }

}
```

However, for some reason, the image will not move, and when I try to move it in other situations at well, it refuses. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Except one missing parenthesis here (but I guess it's not the case in your code) the code have no particular reason to not work. The problem is most likely on how you use it.

My guess is that you are doing something like so :

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var sprite : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode() // A

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // You are creating another `sprite` variable
        // and not using the (A) sprite you declare above
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship") // B

        // Here you set the (B) sprite you just created
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, self.frame.size.height)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        // Here it's still the (B) sprite you just created
        // that you add to the scene
        self.addChild(sprite)

        // You are calling your action from somewhere else
        self.applyAction()

    }

    func applyAction() {
        // You create an action, OK
        let action = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.size.width * 2, duration: 0.5)

        // You apply the action to the (A) sprite property you have in your class
        // Same as : self.sprite.runAction(action)
        sprite.runAction(action)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

In that case, you just have to not create another sprite variable. By removing the `var` keyword on the `// B` line.

Let met know if it helped.
If it's not the case, please give more details (code, ...).

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the case. However, I added information to the question, so hopefully you are able to solve it. Thank you for your contributions!